# XML — How to get two buttons side by side?

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to have two buttons "Run" and "Result" to be side by side. However I'm not having much luck.

I have tried using `RelativeLayout` and also adding `layout_weight` to both buttons but they seem to just disappear and the map to take over the screen.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong and what can be done to fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/myLocationText"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/hello" />
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/resultsHomeTest"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="" />


      <Button
          android:id="@+id/btnRun"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"

          android:text="Run" />


      <Button
          android:id="@+id/btnResults"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Results" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/resultsTextView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text=""
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


  <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/myMapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="02kgJwy0ijcQsVCaCzD9sFv69dOi4gXBEUjIbuQ"

  />

    <!--

    Desktop key: 02kgJwy0ijcTK7fd-wxv7OsPUFEveXTUt16lrRA
    Laptop key : 02kgJwy0ijcQsVCaCzD9sFv69dOi4gXBEUjIbuQ
      -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use  but lint say that it will affect your performance if it is nested

you can use  like the code below

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Slashdot"
        android:id="@+id/textUser" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/textCreatedAt"
        android:text="10 minutes ago"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

But if you have it like the code below, lint will say that it will affect your performance.

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout>
            <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="0.3"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can also use Relative Layout, but don't use weight. If you put them like the code below, you'll just have to manage the margins.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the two buttons inside a horizontal `LinearLayout` :

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">


    <Button
              android:id="@+id/btnRun"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"

              android:text="Run" />


          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btnResults"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Results" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @csmit android:orientation="horizontal" is the default